# SPARQL query gets error from SPARQL Query Validator, but works in Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor

Tags: javascript, sparql, virtuoso

I have a SPARQL query that provides the result when it is run in Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor, but the same query gives a syntax error in SPARQL Query Validator. What is the problem? Why is it showing a  syntax error?

```
PREFIX xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX fn:      <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dc:      <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT ?distractor, (COUNT(DISTINCT ?type) AS ?similarity)
WHERE {
dbr:Jean-Baptiste_Tavernier dct:subject ?subject .
?distractor dct:subject ?subject .
FILTER (!SAMETERM(?distractor, dbr:Jean-Baptiste_Tavernier)) .
dbr:Jean-Baptiste_Tavernier rdf:type ?type .
?distractor rdf:type ?type .
}
GROUP BY ?distractor
ORDER BY DESC(COUNT(DISTINCT ?type))
```

```
syntax error:
Encountered " "," ", "" at line 9, column 19.
Was expecting one of:
     ...
     ...
    "from" ...
    "where" ...
    "(" ...
    "{" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The comma after `SELECT ?distractor,` is allowed in Virtuoso, but is non-standard. After removing the comma (and adding appropriate prefix declarations), the query validates.